# How to bypass SSL error CefSharp WinForms

Tags: c#-4.0, ssl-certificate, cefsharp

I'm using `CefSharp.WinForms` to develop an application.
When any SSL certificate error occurs, it won't display the web page.

How can I bypass SSL certificate error and display the web page?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Option 1 (Preferred)

Implement [IRequestHandler.OnCertificateError](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/89.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_OnCertificateError.htm) - this method will be called for every invalid certificate. If you only wish to override a few methods of `IRequestHandler` then you can inherit from [RequestHandler](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/89.0.x/html/T_CefSharp_Handler_RequestHandler.htm) and `override` the methods you are interested in specifically, in this case `OnCertificateError`

```
//Make sure you assign your RequestHandler instance to the `ChromiumWebBrowser`
browser.RequestHandler = new ExampleRequestHandler();

public class ExampleRequestHandler : RequestHandler
{
    protected override bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        //NOTE: We also suggest you wrap callback in a using statement or explicitly execute callback.Dispose as callback wraps an unmanaged resource.

        //Example #1
        //Return true and call IRequestCallback.Continue() at a later time to continue or cancel the request.
        //In this instance we'll use a Task, typically you'd invoke a call to the UI Thread and display a Dialog to the user
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //NOTE: When executing the callback in an async fashion need to check to see if it's disposed
            if (!callback.IsDisposed)
            {
                using (callback)
                {
                    //We'll allow the expired certificate from badssl.com
                    if (requestUrl.ToLower().Contains("https://expired.badssl.com/"))
                    {
                        callback.Continue(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        callback.Continue(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return true;

        //Example #2
        //Execute the callback and return true to immediately allow the invalid certificate
        //callback.Continue(true); //Callback will Dispose it's self once exeucted
        //return true;

        //Example #3
        //Return false for the default behaviour (cancel request immediately)
        //callback.Dispose(); //Dispose of callback
        //return false;
    }
}
```

---

### Option 2

Set ignore-certificate-errors command line arg

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ignore-certificate-errors");

Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

- [WPF CefSettings Example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/89/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/App.xaml.cs#L16)
- [WinForms CefSettings Example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/89/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs#L26)

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot. But now i am unable in downloading files can u help me with this.

Comment: Got solution for downloading issue from below link :- 
{https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/DownloadHandler.cs#L3}

Comment: Option 1 is currently the only right answer here, as they stopped supporting IgnoreCertificateErrors in [v75.1.141](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases/tag/v75.1.141)

Comment: As @HockeyJ said, IgnoreCertificateErrors no longer works, just attaching the corresponding issue: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2899/cefsettingsignore_certificate_errors-true. As a workaround, you can use a command-line argument: `settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ignore-certificate-errors");`

Comment: I may well be doing it wrong, but the ignore-certificate-errors fake command line isn't working for me either.

Comment: Last report i have suggests the command line argument is working as expected https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2899/cefsettingsignore_certificate_errors-true#comment-58245374 if you are having problems ask a new question that references this one.

Answer (score 8):

Copy/paste ready:

```
//Before instantiating a ChromiumWebBrowser object
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public abstract class BaseRequestEventArgs : System.EventArgs
    {
        protected BaseRequestEventArgs(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
        {
            ChromiumWebBrowser = chromiumWebBrowser;
            Browser = browser;
        }

        public IWebBrowser ChromiumWebBrowser { get; private set; }
        public IBrowser Browser { get; private set; }
    }
    public class OnCertificateErrorEventArgs : BaseRequestEventArgs
    {
        public OnCertificateErrorEventArgs(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
            : base(chromiumWebBrowser, browser)
        {
            ErrorCode = errorCode;
            RequestUrl = requestUrl;
            SSLInfo = sslInfo;
            Callback = callback;

            ContinueAsync = false; // default
        }

        public CefErrorCode ErrorCode { get; private set; }
        public string RequestUrl { get; private set; }
        public ISslInfo SSLInfo { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Callback interface used for asynchronous continuation of url requests.
        ///     If empty the error cannot be recovered from and the request will be canceled automatically.
        /// </summary>
        public IRequestCallback Callback { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Set to false to cancel the request immediately. Set to true and use <see cref="T:CefSharp.IRequestCallback" /> to
        ///     execute in an async fashion.
        /// </summary>
        public bool ContinueAsync { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomRequesthandle : RequestHandler
    {
        public event EventHandler<OnCertificateErrorEventArgs> OnCertificateErrorEvent;

        protected override bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            var args = new OnCertificateErrorEventArgs(chromiumWebBrowser, browser, errorCode, requestUrl, sslInfo, callback);

            OnCertificateErrorEvent?.Invoke(this, args);

            callback.Continue(true);
            return args.ContinueAsync;
        }
    }
```

and

```
 browser = new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser();
        browser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequesthandle();
```

Comment: IRequestCallback.Continue being called immediately after invoking the event doesn't actually allow for the event to handle the certificate error.  E.g. Display a dialog on the UI thread asking user to continue with the invalid certificate.