# C# CefSharp WinForms Connection Using SSL (White Screen)

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am embeding Cefsharp for Winforms version 63.0.3 inside a Windows Forms Host in WPF. I have tried running the simple example and using winforms CefSharp inside the Windows Forms Host works fine.
(https://www.google.com)
image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrt7z.jpg

However when I use other ssl url , but renders a white screen instead of the website.
(https://portal.aoacloud.com.tw/desk_auth_index.php)
image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9apw.jpg

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitBrowser();
    }

    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
    private void InitBrowser()
    {
        CefSettings cfsettings = new CefSettings();
        cfsettings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;
        Cef.Initialize(cfsettings);
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://portal.aoacloud.com.tw/desk_auth_index.php");

        browser.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        this.browser.Size = new Size(321, 421);
        this.browser.Location = new Point(259, 37);
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/58219535/9836179

Answer (score 0):

I find answer form here
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;

namespace CefBlog3
{
  static class Program
  {
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
  Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings() { CachePath = "Cache" } );

  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
}
}
```